# Access state in container component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

How can I access (get and set) state inside a container component?

I am getting `Undefined is not an object evaluating this.state.*` because it cannot be accessed from `MultiImagePost`. Is there a way to bind `this` to the container component?

```
export default class ImagePost extends React.Component {
    state = {
        index: 0,
        modalVisible: false,
        currentImages: []
    };

    render() {
        const { imageCount } = this.props;
        if (imageCount == 1) {
            return <SingleImagePost postObject={this.props} />
        } else {
            return <MultiImagePost postObject={this.props} />
        }
    }

    const MultiImagePost = ({ postObject }) => (
        <View>
            <FlatList
                data={[{key: 'a'}]}
                renderItem={({item}) => 
                    <TouchableOpacity>
                        <View>
                            <FlatGrid
                            itemDimension={100}
                            items={postObject.images}
                            renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                                <TouchableHighlight
                                    onPress={() => {
                                        this.setState({ 
                                            modalVisible: true, 
                                            index: this.state.index, 
                                            currentImages: postObject.images 
                                        });
                                }}>
                                    <Image
                                    source={{ uri: item }}
                                    />
                                </TouchableHighlight>
                            )}
                            />
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                }
            />
        </View>
    );

}
```

Comment: you are defining const within a class, this isnt valid syntax

Comment: Hi Onichan, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

MultiImagePost is a stateless(functional) component,  so it has no state.
U should manage state in ImagePost or consider using React hook.

I can't run your code, if MultiImagePost is inside  ImagePost, you may try  to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have mixed up class component with functional component. You need to change your code a bit like,

```
export default class ImagePost extends React.Component {
  state = {
    index: 0,
    modalVisible: false,
    currentImages: []
  };

  render() {
    const { imageCount } = this.props;
    if (imageCount == 1) {
      return <SingleImagePost postObject={this.props} />
    } else {
      return <>{this.MultiImagePost(this.props)}</>  //Instead of component make it as function call
    }
  }

  //Make this as instance function
  MultiImagePost = (postObject) => (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={[{key: 'a'}]}
        renderItem={({item}) => 
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <View>
              <FlatGrid
                itemDimension={100}
                items={postObject.images}
                renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                  <TouchableHighlight
                    onPress={() => {
                      this.setState({ 
                        modalVisible: true, 
                        index: this.state.index, 
                        currentImages: postObject.images 
                      });
                  }}>
                    <Image source={{ uri: item }} />
                  </TouchableHighlight>
                )}
              />
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        }
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```